# How to avoid php parse_url return false when parse "/s?a=12&b=12.3.3.4:1233" which has ":" in the params?

Tags: php, parse-url

How to avoid php parse_url return false when parse ''/s?a=12&b=12.3.3.4:1233" **which has ":" in the params**?

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                         
var_dump(parse_url('/s?a=12&b=12.3.3.4:1233', PHP_URL_QUERY));
```

returns

```
bool(false)
```

Here is the online run test result:

https://3v4l.org/8LKIV

---

while test good in php 7.1.7

```
print_r(parse_url('/s?a=12&b=12.3.3.4:1233', PHP_URL_QUERY));
```

return good:

```
a=12&b=12.3.3.4:1233
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP7 you can leave out the `scheme` and `host`, but below that version you cant.

So you should also always include the scheme and host.

```
<?php
echo 'Without scheme and host'.PHP_EOL;
print_r(parse_url('/s?a=12&b=12.3.3.4:1233', PHP_URL_QUERY));

echo PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

echo 'With scheme and host'.PHP_EOL;
print_r(parse_url('http://example.com/s?a=12&b=12.3.3.4:1233', PHP_URL_QUERY));
```

**Output for 7.0.0 - 7.2.0**

```
Without scheme and host
a=12&b=12.3.3.4:1233

With scheme and host
a=12&b=12.3.3.4:1233
```

**Output for 5.6.0 - 5.6.30, hhvm-3.18.5 - 3.22.0**

```
Without scheme and host



With scheme and host
a=12&b=12.3.3.4:1233
```

https://3v4l.org/EQhh6

Comment: Good solution!  And is there a way to parse just the Partial URLs correctly?

Comment: What do you mean? Just make sure you have a scheme and host, the value can be fake.

Comment: Ive come to know this issue when checking domain names, if you don't add the scheme, weird things happen for < PHP 5.6.7, so I just prepend it to test.

Comment: I mean that how can we fix it if we don't add the scheme and host to the beginning of partial url string.

Comment: Upgrade to > PHP 7 :/ or prepend a fake one.

Comment: As of writing, there is no mention of this behaviour/change in the PHP docs - https://i.imgur.com/aJ8rkg0.png

Comment: Wired,  but I found that parse_url was mentioned in [php-7.1 source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.1/UPGRADING#L225) upgrading file. May be it was fixed in php7.1.

Comment: Nice find, yeah it works fine for > PHP7.0, though if you intend to move the script to a server which has 5.6 etc I recommend you still fake it to make it more portable.